# Can't add XStream file dependency to Android Studio project

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xstream

I have downloaded and added `xstream-1.4.8.jar` to my Android Studio project. When I build the project it works fine but when I try to run it I get the following error from the Gradle Build window:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/thoughtworks/xstream/mapper/LambdaMapper.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 14.974 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I have looked at the related answers on here and none of the suggested solutions work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

`XStream 1.4.8` is compiled for `Java 8` and the latest version Android supports is `Java 7`.

One solution is to use `XStream 1.4.7`, that works with Android, and another to download `XStream 1.4.8` sources and compile them yourself. In that case you will have to remove `LambdaMapper.java` and possibly some other problematic classes.

Also you can have issues with different versions of `xmlpull` parser used. In that case you can exclude one from compiling.

```
compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
}
```

Comment: Hi, I worked that out shortly after posting the question. I am now using XStream 1.4.7. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: They now released [1.4.10-java7](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/49) It does not contain any stuff of Java 8.

Comment: Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 seems not to accept anymore the exclude command you posted. It works on 2.3.3 though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335142/android-gradle-plugin-3-0-0-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-xmlpull-mxp1-mxparse

Comment: @OneWorld Works fine for me. Maybe some other combination triggers the error. I could not build one project before I deleted .gradle folder from project (not XStream related error). Others didn't have such issues and all use XStream.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You were right. I finally found the combination: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335142/android-gradle-plugin-3-0-0-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-xmlpull-mxp1-mxparse/48560428#48560428