# Enabling R8 causes "android.view.InflateException Error inflating class TextView" in TextView with fontFamily

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I'm trying to shrink/obfuscate my release build with R8 (AS 3.3) but it's crashing trying to inflate an XML file, specifically on a TextView with a fontFamily. Removing the fontFamily attribute fixes the issue.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_linear_gradient"
    tools:context=".login.LoginFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/familyIcon"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/auth_login_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView   <!-- This is line 20 -->
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:lineHeight="24dp"
        android:maxWidth="168dp"
        android:text="@string/login_title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_bold" <!-- Removing this line fixes it -->
        android:textColor="@color/kineduWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/authForm"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/familyIcon" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/authForm"
        layout="@layout/auth_form"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:maxWidth="324dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/familyIcon" />

    <!-- More views... -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
2019-01-17 17:37:26.496 24514-24514/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.mParseState' on a null object reference
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getAttributeListValue(XmlBlock.java:320)
        at androidx.core.content.res.FontResourcesParserCompat.androidx.core.content.res.FontResourcesParserCompat$FamilyResourceEntry parse(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,android.content.res.Resources)(SourceFile:1)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.android.graphics.Typeface loadFont(android.content.Context,android.content.res.Resources,android.util.TypedValue,int,int,androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback,android.os.Handler,boolean)(SourceFile:14)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.android.graphics.Typeface loadFont(android.content.Context,int,android.util.TypedValue,int,androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback,android.os.Handler,boolean)(SourceFile:3)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.android.graphics.Typeface getFont(android.content.Context,int,android.util.TypedValue,int,androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback)(SourceFile:8)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.android.graphics.Typeface getFont(int,int,androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback)(SourceFile:8)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.void updateTypefaceAndStyle(android.content.Context,androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray)(SourceFile:102)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.void loadFromAttributes(android.util.AttributeSet,int)(SourceFile:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.void <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int)(SourceFile:7)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.void <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet)(SourceFile:2)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView createTextView(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet)(SourceFile:1)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.android.view.View createView(android.view.View,java.lang.String,android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)(SourceFile:30)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.void onSubDecorInstalled(android.view.ViewGroup)(SourceFile:89)
                                                        android.view.View createView(android.view.View,java.lang.String,android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.android.view.View onCreateView(android.view.View,java.lang.String,android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet)(SourceFile:1)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.company.auth.login.LoginFragment.android.view.View onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,android.view.ViewGroup,android.os.Bundle)(SourceFile:7)
```

My font lives in a separate library module.

Font family xml file "res/font/gotham-bold.xml" in `:core`

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/gotham_rnd_bold"/>

    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/gotham_rnd_bold_italic"/>
</font-family>
```

And the actual font "gotham_rnd_bold.otf" is also in this `:core` module under "res/font/

Comment: Try to file an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name

Comment: Hi! I see you have filed this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123054725). I'll post it here for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post here the reason why provided by `R8` developers (from your [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123054725)) for better indexing and reference.

> This happens because you are including program classes in your app
>   that is already in the Android framework. The Proguard configuration
>   rule `-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**` explicitly disables these warnings
>   from the compiler.
>
> Ideally, you should not include any classes in your app that is also
>   in the Android framework. You should be able to identify the
>   dependency that includes org.xmlpull.* and then exclude that module
>   from the dependency. It seems that others have successfully done this,
>   see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486112. If you manage to
>   do this, then you shouldn't get any warnings even if you remove the
>   rule `-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**`.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the rule `-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *;}`. 
>   This trick appears to be used by others
>   (https://github.com/search?q=org.xmlpull.v1+extension=pro&type=Code),
>   but it can be error-prone since your version of org.xmlpull.* may be
>   different from the one in the Android framework.
>
> Note that we are working on changing the behavior of R8 such that it
>   deals with duplicate classes in a way such that Android framework
>   classes always take precedence of program classes (b/120884788). In
>   principle, none of the above changes should be needed with that fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom font programatically such as;

```
customText.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, 
R.font.your_font)
```